# Parallel Query Execution while Sync in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync Framework to sync data in N-Tier Client Server architecture. Synchronization works fine when there is low volume of data to be synchronized. However, when there is large volume of data to be synchronized, I am facing database locking issue. The primary reason for this behavior seems to be long running transactions, which causes other transactions from multiple sync agents to be blocked. I have tested this for following:

Sql Server 2008 --> Physical Machine/ VM - Failed, having locking issue

Sql Server 2008 R2 --> Physical Machine/ VM - Succeeded on Physical, Failed on VM

Kindly suggest, what can be the issue which is causing this behavior. I believe this behavior is out of the Sync Framework domain, as sync framework opens a transaction for a batch (I am using batching in sync) and commits when the batch is done. However, I cannot understand the behavior when multiple database objects are locked (long running transactions, even at a point I have noticed almost all of the table objects were locked!),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync Fx does not explicitly issue locks.

It's just like any other database applications though, during sync, some rows will be locked as it applies changes. whether it locks only few rows or the entire table depends on SQL Server promoting or escalating locks from row,page or table.

since, its just like any other database app, you can use the same techniques for investigating the locking issue (e.g., profiling, sp_who, etc...)

if your sync groups/sync scopes are big (many tables), you may consider breaking them down into smaller groups so they can commit faster and reduce the potential concurrency issues. frequent syncs will also help reduce the potential for locking issues if you're updating lesser number of rows.

Comment: Well, the issue is on Sync Framework side. There is a new Property "ApplicationTransactionSize" in Sync Fx 2.1. It is by default 0. This property takes size in KB and when it is set to 0, then all batches are applied in a single transaction, when its size is set then it opens a transaction with the given size. I set this property and everything works like a charm. Correct me if I left/ missed something.

Comment: Again, the ApplicationTransactionSize does not issue an explicit lock. it only tells Sync Fx how much to commit at any given time. the lower you set this, then the more frequent it will commit smaller chunks of the transactions so the shorter the locks are held. take note that this in KB, and depending in row size, you may still end up with few or hundreds if not thousands of rows locked. also by setting batch size and applicationtransaction size, you are actually slowing down the sync since the framework has to break down the changes in chunks.

Comment: Yes performance will be degraded, i understand it, but if we do not set this property why sync framework process all batches in a single transaction? I assumed it processes each batch in a separate transaction, [http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/things-you-need-to-know-about-sql-data-sync-service/](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/things-you-need-to-know-about-sql-data-sync-service/) read **Batching**.

Comment: i'm the author of the blog you just cited. batching has nothing to do with transactions. its just about breaking up the upload of the change dataset in chunks. once the batch files are uploaded, they will be reconstituted as a dataset and applied. im not saying you should not set applicationtransactionsize, i'm just saying there is nothing in the framework that issues an explicit lock.  applicationtransactionsize  was not meant to fix issues with locking, its for addressing unreliable connections.

Comment: Yes i know you are the author of the blog, a pretty much good blog. If you read my question I have clearly mentioned, this issue is not on Sync Framework side. But my question still remain there: why it opens a single transaction for all batches? Any specific reason for that, since it is an obvious requirement to divide batches in transactions.

Comment: this is your first comment on this answer "Well, the issue is on Sync Framework side.". why would it open multiple transactions for the batches? as i have mentioned, the batching has nothing to do with transactions. instead of sending one large dataset over the wire, batching breaks it down to individual files. these files are then use to rebuild the dataset and that's when it applies the changes. and read the title of the blog post again, that is Azure SQL Data Sync Service, although its built using Sync Framework, they are not the same.